# Odoo 10: Is multi-company with multi-currency setup stable for production?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to setup accounting, sales, purchase and warehouse inventory management for two connected trading companies under Odoo 10. The companies share the **same products and owner**, but are:

- registered as **independent companies** in two different countries (multi-company option)
- with **different currencies** (multi-currency option) and
- require **separate accounting** (two parallel chart of accounts)

I am worried that such a multi-company + multi-currency + two different chart of accounts setup might put me in rather "un-tested terrain". Does someone have practical experience with such a setup and could provide feedback? Is Odoo 10 sufficiently tested and stable in such a setup? Would the benefits of having all in one place (single database) out-weight potential pitfalls and short-comings? A clear benefit would be, to be able to see all stock locations at once. If you have setup Odoo for a similar multi company/inventory/accounting scenario, how did you do it (separate or single database, any important work-arounds) and would you do it again in the same way if you had to do it again from start?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find it stable ?!!

Did you find all the bugs in multi-company ?

Did you discover the bad design of multi-currency implementation ?

My answer based on lots of hands-on-experience is: A big No, it's not stable and not even tested well.